# Strange issue with Json & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

There is any reason why a json string fail to be evaluated (`transport.responseText.evalJSON();`) on the server but works on my local installation ?

I'm doing a simple ajax request like this one:

```
new Ajax.Request(
        this.saveUrl, {
            method: 'post',
            parameters: Form.serialize(this.form),
            onLoading: function () {
                totals.update('<div class="loading-ajax">&nbsp;</div>');
            },
            onSuccess: function (transport) {
                if (transport.status == 200) {
                    var data = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                    totals.update(data.shipping_method);
                }
            },
            onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout)
        }
    );
```

On server side I output an array containing some html:

```
 $data = array(
            'shipping_method' => $shipping_method,
            'payment_method' => $payment_method
        );

echo json_encode($data);
```

I have tried to valorize `$total` and '$other' as empty string `''` but I get the same result:
`transport.responseText.evalJSON();` return an `"unexpected token"`

As said above the weird thing is that on my local it works ( the output is the same as the server but js doesn't trigger any error )

I'm struggling with this almost all day ... any help is really appreciate thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
console.log(transport.responseText) 
-> {"shipping_method":"","payment_method":""}
```

Inspecting the server response 'network tab' in chrome I can see a small difference, in comparison to my local: there is a small `red dot` before the response content if ( is say `\ufeff` if I move the mouse over it, I'm not sure about the meaning ... )

[image]

Comment: What happens when you do JSON.parse(transport.responseText)? And can you show the ouput of console.log(transport.responseText)

Comment: Have you tried the "Network" tab on your "Element inspector", available on your favorite browser?

Comment: You could try using [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) instead off evalJSON. Its what I tend to use, not sure what your actual error is though

Comment: If the output is the same and the Javascript code is the same - then it works. You are making some wrong assumption.

Comment: Have you configured charset in your php response header ?

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: indeed @angellica.araujo I think you pointed the finger in the right direction:
`\ufeff` character looks to be the guilty ( I' m not sure why on my local this doesn't not create issue but on the server yes )

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark so probably one of your php servers has mbstring extension and the other one doesn't.

Comment: I have checked and both live server and local server has the `mbstring extension` enabled ... anyother idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some test I found out that the issue is encoding used in some PHP files, my co-worked had the brilliant idea to switch to ANSI. (ISO-8859)

For some reason these files coded with ANSI produced JSON content to be different:

- chrome inspector was showing `a red dot` -> [`Byte_order_mark`](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) `\ufeff` character (aka `BOM`)

This probably means the BOM character is missing and **this was breaking the json parse.**

**SOLUTION:**

After I parsed and cleaned all my project files from the BOM character, chrome doesn't show the red dot in the inspector and **the issue is gone**

Still it is not clear why on my local installation the issue was not present while on the server it was ( both linux ) but there are probably multiple settings involved here ...

To clean your files see: [Elegant way to search for UTF-8 files with BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom)

Comment: Was go through same issues. Thanks for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use map function to evaluate json value

```
       $.map(transport, function (item){    
 totals.update(item.total);;
       });
```

I think its Working fine

Comment: I would suggest him to use JSON.parse() instead, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299644/why-does-this-json-parse-return-error-unexpected-token-illegal